# How do i delete old disk after after converting unmanged to managed in azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have converted my VM from un managed to managed mode now i want to delete the old disk of the VM. Can somebody help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unmanaged VM needs a Storage Account to manage the unmanaged disk file by the customer self. But the managed VM does not need a Storage Account to manage the disk file.

So, the easiest way is to delete the Storage Account directly. If you need to remain the Storage Account, you can navigate to the managed disk and will find the source blob of the old disk, the screenshot here:

[image]

Then go to the container and delete the vhd file.

Comment: Thank you Charles